# The effect of pressure on boiling point?

Tags: equilibrium, boiling-point, vapor-pressure, pressure

My textbook states the following:

[image: Textbook statement]

Qualitatively, I understand why the boiling point of a substance increases when the pressure is increased. However, I learned that if the pressure is increased when the reaction system is at equilibrium, the volume of the system ***decreases*** and hence, the reaction will proceed in that direction in which the volume of the system ***increases***. In the above scenario, however, it has been given that water in the gaseous form occupies more volume than its liquid form and so, shouldn't the given reaction proceed in the ***forward*** direction, hence ***reducing*** the boiling point?

Please note that I am convinced and I believe that it makes sense for the boiling point to ***increase*** when the pressure increases but can somebody please explain the flaw in my reasoning with regard to the given equilibrium?

Much thanks in advance :) Regards.

Comment: what's the reaction in boiling of water?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What do you mean by "reaction of boiling of water"?

Comment: There is no reaction in boiling water, why do you apply le chatliers principle?

Comment: There is no chemical reaction but there is a physical reaction, no? An equilibrium does exist between the gas phase and the liquid phase of water(or any liquid, for that matter).

Comment: at equilibrium ratio of concentration of products to concentration of reactants remain constant. (K_c) . How would you apply this to a physical change?

Comment: In this case, we use Kp=Pressure(of water vapour). At equilibrium, this will be equal to the vapor pressure of the water at that temperature.

Comment: Yeah then what, As you decrease volume partial pressure of water increases and to maintain same K_c the partial pressure of water has to decrease this is by its dissolution into liquid water.

Comment: The equilibrium will shift in a direction in which the pressure decreases, yes? So it shifts in the direction of the liquid phase for which pressure is...not defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your flaw in the logic lies in that you think that the volume of the system includes the liquid. Le Chatelier's principle on pressure equilibrium only applies to when the compound involved is in gaseous phase, in an ideal sense. Therefore if you increase the pressure (decreasing the volume), then the reaction will progress towards the direction where gas volume DECREASES, which is towards liquid phase. Overall, the entire apparatus increases the vapor pressure on the gas (gas pressure on the external pressure), which increases the boiling point.

Comment: OK, but on decreasing volume, why does the reaction progress in that direction in which the volume further decreases?

Comment: Le Chatelier's principle states that a reaction that undergoes a change in pressure, temperature, or volume, the equilibrium shifts towards the direction of the reaction that counteracts and subsists with that change. In this case, the change in volume causes an equilibrium shift that subsists by decreasing the volume

Comment: The shift in equilibrium should be such that it counteracts the stress(change) applied, yes? So **why**, on **decreasing** the volume, will the equilibrium shift in a direction in which the volume **further decreases**?!

Comment: Decreasing the volume increases the pressure. The volume decreases because the pressure increase causes the gas to contract. Look at this link for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle#Effect_of_change_in_pressure

Comment: So if I decrease the pressure, the volume increases and the reaction will shift in that direction in which the volume further increases? Seems very absurd sir/ma'am. I think it should shift in that direction in which the volume decreases, causing the pressure to increase.

Comment: I really don't know what to say. Its Le Chateliers principle.

Comment: But it's not! Please read my comment again; doesn't it seem like the situation that I'm describing is the exact opposite of the outcome given by the principle?!

Comment: Can I get some help here? The volume of the system DECREASES, which means the systems gas' pressure MUST INCREASE. To counteract this, aka reduce the increased pressure, the volume of the GAS mudt decrease

Comment: What are you even saying?! "To counteract the increased pressure, the volume of the gas must **decrease**?!" However are you **counteracting** the change if you're decreasing the volume even further?! $P$ is inversely proportional to $V$!

Comment: Please calm down. The changes in VOLUME is not the actual thing that affects the equilibrium. The change in VOLUME, changes the pressure to be HIGHER, which is what actually shifts the equilibrium. Le Chatelier's principle is about how external forces affect the equilibrium point.

Comment: OK, sorry (:P). Since the decreased volume increases the pressure of the gas, according to Le Chatelier's principle, the equilibrium tends to shift in that direction in which its pressure decreases, yes? For a *decrease* in pressure, the volume *increases*.  Hence, on decreasing the volume of a gas mixture at equilibrium, it tends to shift in that direction in which its volume increases.

Answer (score -3):

It's because when we increase pressure, we are actually increasing external pressure so according to Le Chatelier's principle, to counteract the effect it should increase the internal pressure. This is the reason that the reaction shifts where internal volume decreases, so that internal pressure increases.

Comment: Could you please edit your post so that you are usually complete words? It is difficult to understand the content of your answer with the incomplete words.